# Best way to send TypedArray data from NodeJS to Python using python-shell

Tags: python, node.js

I'm trying to send data from NodeJS to process in Python using python-shell. My Python script requires a float32 array but I am not sure how to send that data type using python-shell. I can send a string without issue and I know my python script works fine otherwise. Is there a way to send the array directly or do I need to do some data conversion or parsing in python?

Here is what I am trying right now:

In Python:

```
import sys
input = sys.stdin.read()
print type(input)
```

In Node:

```
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');
var pyshell = new PythonShell('script.py', {mode:'binary'});
// data is float32 TypedArray
pyshell.send(data).end(function(err){
    if (err){console.log(err, 'did not work')};
});
pyshell.on('message', function (message) {
    console.log('message received', message); 
});
```

Here I get the following error:

```
net.js:655
    throw new TypeError(
    ^

TypeError: Invalid data, chunk must be a string or buffer, not object
    at Socket.write (net.js:655:11)
    at PythonShell.send (/project/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:205:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/project/server.js:59:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
```

If I convert the TypedArray to string it sends fine but it feels wrong to receive this long string in Python rather than an array. I'm sure there is a simple fix. Any advice would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer

The message suggests you could use a buffer object, that should be the way to go.

Comment: I agree that this seems like the best option. If I send in a JS buffer (e.g. Buffer.from('test')) I don't get the above error and I the success callback is hit on the pyshell.send() call but for some reason the python script is not executed. I am wondering if it has to do with using {mode:'binary'}? I don't have a working example binary mode for a buffer as of yet

Comment: Got it =) Thank you. Will accept my answer in 2 days when SO lets me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end I converted my float32 arrays to javascript Buffer objects and used 'binary' mode. Also I needed to switch from pyshell.on to pyshell.stdout.on which is in the python-shell test scripts for binary mode but not in the readme...

In Node:

```
var options = {mode: 'binary'};
var pyshell = new PythonShell('test.py', options);
var data =  Buffer.from(myFloat32TypedArray.buffer, 'float32');     

pyshell.send(data).end((err) => {
    if (err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        console.log('data sent');
    };
});
    
pyshell.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

In Python:

```
input_data = np.frombuffer(sys.stdin.read(), dtype=np.float32)
sys.stdout.write(input_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about a direct way (which I assume isn't available as well) but you can use `JSON.stringify` on the javascript side to convert the array into a string, send it to python, read it as raw input and convert that back into a json object (which will be an array).

**JAVASCRIPT SIDE:**

```
var a = [1,2,3];
pyshell.send(JSON.stringify(data), ....)
```

**PYTHON SIDE:**

```
import json,sys
input = sys.stdin.read()
print(json.loads(input))
```

Answer (score 0):

In Node:

```
let shell_bin = new PythonShell('test.py', { mode: 'binary' });
shell_bin.on('stderr', function (stderr) {
  console.log((stderr));
});

let myFloat32TypedArray = new Float32Array(10);
myFloat32TypedArray[1] = 10.0;
var data =  Buffer.from(myFloat32TypedArray.buffer, 'float32');     
shell_bin.send(data).end((err) => {
  if (err){
      console.log(err);
  }else{
      console.log('data sent');
  };
});
    
shell_bin.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log(data);
  let myFloat32TypedArray = new Float32Array(data.buffer);
  console.log(myFloat32TypedArray);
});
```

In Python:

```
import sys, numpy as np

xb = sys.stdin.buffer.read()
input_data = np.frombuffer(xb, dtype=np.float32)
sys.stdout.buffer.write(input_data)
```